# CakePHP custom pagination / paginator in controller not working as expected - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: function, cakephp, sorting, controller, pagination

I can get my find to work any other way, but I cannot get this working with pagination. What am I doing wrong?

**Output in view:**

```
SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'fields' in 'where clause'

Warning (2):** Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at...
```

**Controller Action:**

```
...
$cond = array(
        'fields'     => array('id', 'name', 'provider_network_url', 'application_url'),
        'conditions' => array('PlanDetail.id' => $id),
        'contain'    => array(
            'Company' => array('fields' => array(
                'id',
                'name',
                'company_logo_url',
                'plan_detail_by_company_landing')),
            'Plan'    => array('fields'     => array('id', 'monthly_cost'),
                'Applicant'  => array('fields' => array('id', 'name')),
                'Age'        => array('fields' => array('id', 'name')),
                'State'      => array('fields' => array('id', 'name')),
                'Zip'        => array('fields' => array('id', 'title')),
                'PlanDetail' => array('fields' => array('id', 'name')),
            )));
    $planDetails = $this->paginate('PlanDetail', $cond);
    $this->set(compact('planDetails', $planDetails));
...
```

Comment: what is the sql query generated? (You'll need debug set to 2 to see that). And `$this->set(compact('planDetails'));`

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->paginate = array(
        'fields'     => ....,
        'conditions' => ....,
        'contain'    => array(
            'Company' => ...,
            'Plan'    => ....));
    $this->set('planDetails', $this->paginate()));
```

Comment: I must be doing something fundamentally wrong. I can pull the array in now with your suggestion, but my condition clause: 'conditions' => array('PlanDetail.id' => $id) is not being applied to the results, and I cannot access the array elements as I would expect. For example, I can access anything at the ['PlanDetail'] level, but if I try to access: ['Plan'] I get an invalid index. But the [Plan] is showing up in the Array as expected. This all works fine when I used a standard find()..

Comment: read the sql that is generated. cake uses multi find queries not one query that is joined where you can set conditions.